# Open a modal window before user navigates away from page or refreshes page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to use the AngularJS ModalsService to open a modal window warning a user that unsaved changes on their form will be lost of they navigate away or refresh the page.  It should ask them if they wish to continue and if they click OK the navigation/reload should occur as before if they click Cancel it should close the modal and stop the navigation/reload.

I've got a directive that creates a window when this occurs but the window ignores my applications style.

acConfirmExit Directive

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('SomeModule').directive('acConfirmExit', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            acConfirmExit: '&',
            confirmMessageWindow: '@',
            confirmMessageRoute: '@',
            confirmMessage: '@'
        },
        link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                if ($scope.acConfirmExit()) {
                    // Launch modal instance
                    return $scope.confirmMessageWindow || $scope.confirmMessage;
                }
            }
            var $locationChangeStartUnbind = $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {
                if ($scope.acConfirmExit()) {
                    if (!confirm($scope.confirmMessageRoute || $scope.confirmMessage)) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });

            $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                window.onbeforeunload = null;
                $locationChangeStartUnbind();
            });
        }
    };
});
}());
```

HTML

```
<div ac-confirm-exit="dirty" 
confirm-message-window="Unsaved changes to this DataDoc. All your changes will be lost." 
confirm-message-route="Unsaved changes to this DataDoc.  Leave this page without saving your changes?"></div>
```

**EDIT:**
Apologies I wasn't being clear, I want to use a modal popup window rather than the standard browser window that opens.  I'm just not sure how to use the modal window with window.onbeforeunload and $locationChangeStart is all.

Comment: are you using ui-router or stock angular routing?

Comment: stock angular routing

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because your code doesn't have a angular context, they are in a raw window event "onbeforeunload".

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if ($scope.acConfirmExit()) {
        // Launch modal instance
        return $scope.confirmMessageWindow || $scope.confirmMessage;
    }
}
```

try to inject $window and code this:

```
// inject $window
angular.module('SomeModule').directive('acConfirmExit', function ($window) {

// listen onbeforeunload with $window
$window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if ($scope.acConfirmExit()) {
        // Launch modal instance
        return $scope.confirmMessageWindow || $scope.confirmMessage;
    }
}
```